# How to position a CSS sprite background image within the element?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a sprite image being used as a background:

```css
#block {
  width: 143px;
  height: 144px;
  background: #0f0 url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) no-repeat -91px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

I want to position the background image at a specific top/left offset (for example 10px from the top and left of the container element). How can I do this?

Comment: The background-position rule. This is a great resource I use when generating sprites. http://www.spritecow.com/ Looks like you're using it to some extent in the short-hand background rule.

Comment: No, `background-position` is for selecting the location of the image within the sprite image

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use CSS sprite you can't position it the way you want. but this solution might help. Using `margin` on an additional element having the background image in order to position it:

```css
.BlockBox {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#block {
  margin: 100px 0 0 10px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) no-repeat -91px 0;
}

<div class="BlockBox">
    <div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w31k97mL/)**.

Comment: Ah, okay...so CSS simply does not provide a way to "position" the background sprite using a single element?

Comment: CSS provides a way to position a background image – no more, no less. The fact that there is more than one “image” in the sprite makes it necessary to position it within an element with limited dimensions, so that the other parts of the sprite don’t show as well – so you can not position it arbitrarily in a bigger element. Instead of putting another element in the HTML however one could use a pseudo-element of specific dimensions.

Comment: You can also use a psuedo element, attach the background image to it and then position it as needed if you'd like to avoid adding an element to your HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/ttmw5en5/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0x;
```

Comment: No, that positions the element, not the background.

Comment: Sorry, you could either use margin on other object or use -20px